# Converting a Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> to Map<String,Integer> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I would like to convert a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>` to a `Map<String,Integer>` using `Stream`s.

Here's the catch (and why I can't seem to figure it out):

I would like to group my Integer-Values by the Key-Values of the corresponding Maps. So, to clarify:

I have Entries like those:

```
Entry 1: ["A",["a",1]]

Entry 2: ["B",["a",2]]

Entry 3: ["B",["b",5]]

Entry 4: ["A",["b",0]]
```

I want to convert that structure to the following:

```
Entry 1: ["a",3]

Entry 2: ["b",5]
```

I think that with the `Collectors` class and methods like `summingInt` and `groupingBy` you should be able to accomplish this. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to go about this, though.

It should be noted that all the inner `Map`s are guaranteed to always have the same keys, either with `Integer`-value 0 or sth > 0. (e.g. "A" and "B" will both always have the same 5 keys as one another)
Everything I've tried so far pretty much ended nowhere. I am aware that, if there wasn't the summation-part I could go with sth like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> map2= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
                map1.values().stream().forEach(map -> {
                    map2.putAll(map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue())));
                });
```

But how to add the summation part?

Comment: you can't have those 4 entries, the keys are the same, it's only 2

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I believe the OP meant that the inner Map of key "A" has two entries, as does the inner Map of key "B"

Comment: correct. The inner maps have the same, but those are different maps, since they are in different entrys of the outer map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing Map by using Java 8 Stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851350/reducing-map-by-using-java-8-stream-api)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

First create a `Stream` of the entries of all the inner maps, and then group the entries by key and sum the values having the same key.

```
Map<String,Integer> map2 = 
    map1.values()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) // create a Stream of all the entries 
                                            // of all the inner Maps
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                      Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```